# Get selected radio buttons of certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the radio buttons that has a certain class that is selected.

Getting the radio buttons of that class comes with

```
$("input:radio.someClass");
```

I thought that this would work to get the selected radio button -

```
$("input:radio.someClass:selected");
```

But that returns empty - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use $("input:radio.someClass:checked")

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to JQuery documentation.

The `:selected` selector works for  option elements. It does not work for checkboxes or radio inputs;

Try:

```
$("input:radio.someClass:checked");
```

Comment: i want in javascript not jquery

Answer (score 5):

select all checked radio buttons having someclass
and then loop through all and get their value

```
var v= $('input[type=radio].someclass:checked');
$(v).each(function(i){
alert($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of this

`$("input:radio.someClass:selected");`

try this one

```
$("input:radio.someClass:checked");
```

Answer (score 3):

This may solve your problem.

```
$('input[name=radioName].someClass:checked').val();
```

OR

```
$("input[type='radiobutton'].someClass:checked");
```

If not then comment.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
$('input[class=someClass]:checked', '#yourForm').val();
```

For best performance jquery documentation recommends [Jquery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) using type instead of :radio selector

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#yourForm').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this script

```
$("input:radio.classNmae:checked").val();
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer? See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
var template_id = $('input[name=template_id].checkbox-tools:checked').val();

$.ajax({

      url: campaign_email_url,
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
      data: {
           template_id: template_id,
     },
     success: function (data) {
           alert('Campaign updated!!');
     },
     error: function (data) {
           alert('Campaign error!!');
      }

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this:

```js
let values = [];

$('.yourclass:checked').each(() => {
  let radiovalue = $(this).val();
  values.push(radiovalue);
});
```