# Get value of radio button inside for loop

Tags: javascript, php

i am using for loop as below

```
<?php foreach($vtype as $vtypes) { ?>  
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="type<?php echo $vtypes['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $vtypes['id'];?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

And in javascript i want to get the values of radio button clicked but everytime i click on radio button i am getting only the first value.
my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
</script>
```

Comment: `ID`s must be unique on your page. You are duplicating them in loop

Comment: Wow, how many radio buttons with ID as `'type'` are there..

Comment: i can use unique id in input box . but how to retrieve them in javascript

Comment: you should have unique id in document, better use class selector.

Comment: There are 5 radio buttons of  id type

Comment: Add class to radio and try to get value using jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677337/get-selected-radio-buttons-of-certain-class

Answer (score 2):

Please use it:

```
document.querySelector('input[name=type]:checked').value
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP is actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this scenario. No matter how many checkbox you have

```js
function getValue(data){
  alert(data.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="1" onclick="getValue(this)">
<input type="radio" value="2" onclick="getValue(this)">
<input type="radio" value="3" onclick="getValue(this)">
```

Comment: In this case i am not getting alert..i am using bootstrap when i click on radio button i am not getting any alert

Comment: you mean jquery, javascript should work on every browser

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($vtype as $key=> $vtypes)  { ?>  
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="type_<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $vtypes['id'];?>" />
```

Here is javascript call

```
$(document).on("change","input[type=radio]",function(){
    var ac=$('[name="type"]:checked').val();
    alert(ac);
});
```